# Htaccess rewriterule and special characters '&'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make some really simple redirection from an old to a new website. But all my redirection with the character '&' dont work.

For exemple:

```
    RewriteRule ^-Nos-equipes-$ /-Associes-Collaborateurs-?lang=fr [R=301,L]
```

work fine, but:

```
    RewriteRule ^-Contact-?&lang=en$ /-Nous-contacter-?lang=en [R=301,L]
```

Dont work.

I am sure its easy, but i dont find anyway to make it work. I have try flag [NE] , or write [&]...

Thanks. Casp.

## EDIT:

I now use the solution anubhava who works;
but not totaly cause my problem is more complexe; 
In fact i got some url with param:

```
 ?&lang=en, ?&lang=fr, and ?lang=en
```

So i have had other query string like that:

```
# Redirection from the old site #--------------------------------------
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=fr(&|$)
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=en(&|$)
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en(&|$)
```

This work still great; except in 2 cases:
the first one:
trying to make this redirection (stay on same url but juste modify the param)

```
    RewriteRule ^the_url?&lang=en$ /the_url?lang=en [R=301]
```

who make an redirection error.

And second case when i have to rewrite the same url but with different param:

```
    RewriteRule ^the_url$ /other_url?lang=fr [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^the_url?&lang=en$ /other_url?lang=en [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^the_url?&lang=fr$ /other_url?lang=fr [R=301,L]
```

It works but only with the first one insruction.
(i dont put the flag L, cause i got a long list of rewrite; i think i can put the condition at the beginning and not rewrite them each-time)

:::::::::::::::::::::::

Exemple of real url that i am trying to redirect who cause trouble

```
    www.mywebsite/-Avocats-a-la-Cour- to--> www.mywebsite/?lang=fr 
    www.mywebsite/-Avocats-a-la-Cour-?&lang=en to--> www.mywebsite/?lang=en 

    www.mywebsite/Marque-francaise?&lang=fr to--> www.mywebsite//Marque-francaise?lang=fr
    www.mywebsite/French-Trademarks?&lang=en to--> www.mywebsite//French-Trademarks?lang=en

    www.mywebsite/-Contact-?&lang=en to--> www.mywebsite/-Nous-contacter-?lang=en
    www.mywebsite/-Contact-?&lang=fr to--> www.mywebsite/-Nous-contacter-?lang=fr

    www.mywebsite/person-780?lang=en to--> www.mywebsite/personel?lang=en
```

Comment: I had some real url in exemple for illustration. Well thanks for your help.. I hope there is a solution. Maybe a way to make it ignore the parameter and consider it like normal text ?

Comment: No your question is not showing any real URLs you're trying to rewrite it is only showing rewrite rules that may or may not be right.

Comment: The rewriterules was to take litteraly like an url; to be more clear i edit the exemple from rewrite rules to URL ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`. You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=en(&|$)
RewriteRule ^-?Contact-?$ /-Nous-contacter- [R=302,NC,L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried over to target URI.

---

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question you can have these rules:

```
# www.mywebsite/-Avocats-a-la-Cour- to--> www.mywebsite/?lang=fr 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(-Avocats-a-la-Cour-)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?lang=fr [R=302,L,NE]

# www.mywebsite/-Avocats-a-la-Cour-?&lang=en to--> www.mywebsite/?lang=en 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(-Avocats-a-la-Cour-)\?&?(lang=en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# www.mywebsite/Marque-francaise?&lang=fr to--> www.mywebsite/Marque-francaise?lang=fr
# www.mywebsite/French-Trademarks?&lang=en to--> www.mywebsite/French-Trademarks?lang=en
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(Marque-francaise|French-Trademarks)\?&(lang=(?:en|fr))\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# www.mywebsite/-Contact-?&lang=en to--> www.mywebsite/-Nous-contacter-?lang=en
# www.mywebsite/-Contact-?&lang=fr to--> www.mywebsite/-Nous-contacter-?lang=fr
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(-Contact-)\?&?(lang=(?:en|fr))\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /-Nous-contacter-?%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# www.mywebsite/person-780?lang=en to--> www.mywebsite/personel?lang=en
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(person-780)\?&?(lang=(?:en|fr))\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /personel?%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i still got some trouble because my situation is a bit more complexe; i got hundrerd of url to redirect and in some case this does'nt work. i edit my post to add the new problem.

Comment: Yes sorry, i was thinking i could just replace the character &, so my initial question was not enough precise. I dont write all the url i have to rewrite because there is too many. I have edited my initial question with more detail. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt look right

```
RewriteRule ^-Contact-?&lang=en$ /-Nous-contacter-?lang=en [R=301,L]
```

I would think the `&` should only be used when you have more than one parameter being passed
e.g.

```
?lang=en&userId=13
```

I would try:

```
RewriteRule ^-Contact-?lang=en$ /-Nous-contacter-?lang=en [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but i have no choice, this is old url that i have to redirect.